# How to set the second and subsequent appearances of an acronym using acro package

Tags: acronyms, acro

I'm using the `acro` package for my acronyms. My supervisor didn't like the use of ancronyms in the text, so I have to put all of them in the long form, but keeping the first style like "acronym (AC)" and the rest of uses "acronym". How can I configure the `acro` package for to print the long form in the second and subsequent uses?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{TIAE}{
short=TIAE,
long=this is an example,
}
\begin{document}
Firt use \ac{TIAE},
then second use \ac{TIAE},  %<--- must be "this is an example"
third use \ac{TIAE} and     %<--- must be "this is an example"
last use \ac{TIAE}.\par     %<--- must be "this is an example"
%
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the point in giving the (AC) on first use if you never use it anywhere else in the text?

Comment: @DaiBowen It will be used in tables and figures and schemas

Comment: @DaiBowen also some terms are more commonly known in some fields by their acronyms (PL vs photoluminescence) for example, but one author/supervisor may not be used to that or may just have a thing against all acronyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a macro which contains `\acifused` to test if the acronym was already used and use `\acl` if true and `\ac` if false:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{TIAE}{
short=TIAE,
long=this is an example,
}
\newcommand{\myac}[1]{\acifused{#1}{\acl{#1}}{\ac{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Firt use \myac{TIAE},
then second use \myac{TIAE},  %<--- must be "this is an example"
third use \myac{TIAE} and     %<--- must be "this is an example"
last use \myac{TIAE}.\par     %<--- must be "this is an example"
%
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the acronym template for all `\ac`-like usages after the first with the `subsequent-style` key. Like `first-style`, `subsequent-style` accepts any defined acronym template, and can be set globally through `\acsetup` or on a per acronym basis in `\DeclareAcronym`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{subsequent-style=long}
\DeclareAcronym{TIAE}{
short=TIAE,
long=this is an example,
subsequent-style=long,
}
\begin{document}
Firt use \ac{TIAE},
then second use \ac{TIAE},  %<--- must be "this is an example"
third use \ac{TIAE} and     %<--- must be "this is an example"
last use \ac{TIAE}.\par     %<--- must be "this is an example"
%
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```